# No converter found for return value of type: class com.google.gson.JsonArray

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax, spring-mvc

I am developing an application where I have two drop down lists. When I select a value from first drop down, second drop down, an ajax call happens to controller and returned list should populate in second drop down list. I have tried below code.

jsp form:

```
    <form:form modelAttribute="place" action="getWeather">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="country">Country:</form:label></td>
                <td>

                    <form:select path="country" id = "countryList">
                        <form:option value="#">--Select--</form:option>
                        <form:options items="${CountriesList}"/>
                    </form:select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="city">City:</form:label></td>
                <td>
                    <form:select path="city" id = "cityList">

                    </form:select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form:form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("countryList").addEventListener("change", myFunction);

/* $(document).ready(function(){
alert("sample msg");    
}); */
function myFunction(){

    var id = $(this).val()
    /* var Country = { "Country" : id }
    alert(Country);
    alert(JSON.stringify(Country)); */
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'GetCities/' + id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            var slctSubcat=$('#cityList'), option="";
            slctSubcat.empty();

            for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                option = option + "<option value='"+data[i] + "'>"+data[i] + "</option>";
            }
            slctSubcat.append(option);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/GetCities/{country}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody JsonArray getCities(@PathVariable(value="country") String Country){
        List<String> cities = getWeatherService.getCities(Country);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(cities, new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType());
        JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
        return jsonArray;
    }
```

Ajax call is successful and getting data in list. But When pass the list to jsp in the form of JsonArray, it is giving exception like below.

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class com.google.gson.JsonArray
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:225)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:182)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I have tried passing List directly, but same issue. Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: what does json array do >

Comment: Seems you need to register a converter with spring MVC so it knows how to convert a `com.google.gson.JsonArray` instance to a clientside string. It would make sense that spring MVC does NOT have a gson dependency by default

Comment: I have already added Gson dependency in my pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to resolve this issue. Instead of returning JsonArray from controller, I have just returned Json string. It worked.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/GetCities/{country}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getCities(@PathVariable(value="country") String Country){
        List<String> cities = getWeatherService.getCities(Country);
        Collections.sort(cities);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(cities);
        return json;
    }
```